# How to restrict a bound Google Apps Script to only files in the folder that contains the Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a Google Apps Script that can make changes the bound Google Sheets file and then copy a subset of those sheets to a new Google Sheets file in the same folder as the activeSpreadsheet containing the Google Apps Script.

I want to avoid having to give the script all drive permissions -- of course, so if something were to go wrong the entire Drive contents cannot be removed.

Comment: Are you referring to restricting the DriveApp Permission in Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

> Authorization Scripts that use this method require authorization with
> one or more of the following scopes:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

This is from Googles documentation on the DriveApp Class: (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#authorization_22)

So what you want can not be done.

You could however create a 2nd google account which you only give access to this one folder and let this account run the script (this way your "main" drive is "safe" since the account that runs the code only has access to the single folder. (if you however for some reason need the ability to run the code from you main acc you could still do the 2nd account thing in deploying as web app (which allows code to be run as the owner).

Comment: We should all band together in requesting Google to provide the facility to restrict a Google Apps Script to a set of folders and their subfolders.  The current environment makes it too easy for a mistake to be made that has dire consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- it matches my research (unfortunately).

Comment: @JoeWhite The consequences are a nuisance at worst - Without any Advanced Services / APIs enabled the only way to "delete" a file is to set it's `isTrashed` value to true. Which will then give you 30 days to restore it. There is also no such thing as "delte All". It's also unlikely to just delete stuff (if you didn't tell the script to delete stuff) - And even if this is only a concern in production, once you've deployed your code this is a non issue (so just test it on a 2ndary account)